# Indexing parameters or not if they provide filtering of the content

Tags: seo, google

I've started a site about selling cars and visitors can filter out the results, which means a lot of pages which get indexed by Google.

My question is should I allow indexing all those filter URL parameters or not?

Example:

```
example.com/search?brand=BMW&fuel_type=diesel&...
```

Also if I should allow indexing those pages what should the title be?

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot shouldn't be crawling these URLs, let alone indexing them. You can specifically tell Google what the parameters mean in Google Search Console. Open the [**URL Parameters**](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) tool and add each parameter. By telling Google what the parameter does (in this case, "displays a subset of content"), Googlebot will act accordingly. You should choose "No URLs" so Googlebot knows not to crawl URLs containing that parameter.

[image]

> **No URLs:** Googlebot won't crawl any URLs containing this parameter. This is useful if your site uses many parameters to filter content. For example, telling Googlebot not to crawl URLs with less significant parameters such as `pricefrom` and `priceto` (like `http://​www.examples.com/​search?category=shoe&​brand=nike&​color=red&​size=5&​pricefrom=10&​priceto=1000`) can prevent the unnecessary crawling of content already available from a page without those parameters (like `http://​www.examples.com/​search?category=shoe&​brand=nike&​color=red&​size=5`).

Answer (score 1):

If all products are accessible to the search engine robots with out filtering (view all/pagination) then either using the URL parameter tool in Search Console or using the robots.txt file to block these URLs from being crawled is the best thing to do.

I would go with the URL parameter tool like @grgarside explained.